# How to generate a range of numbers between two numbers then duplicate entries from that range?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would love some help with a query to expand an Access Table I'm working with. I need to generate a range between the min and max numbers and then duplicate the Code for that range.

```
Code |Number-min|Number-max
----------------------------
1342 |0109724 | 0109728
20040|0116764 | 0116766
```

etc

This is what I am hoping to achieve:

```
Code| NumberALL
----------------
1342 | 0109724  
1342 | 0109725
1342 | 0109726
1342 | 0109727  
1342 | 0109728
20040 | 0116764
20040 | 0116765
20040 | 0116766
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a table `tblInp` with the fields `Code`, `MinNr` (dataype long), `MaxNr` (datatype long) and a `tblOut` with the fields `Code`, `allNr` (datatype long) then the following code will create the data in `tblOut` as described in the post. It just loops through all records in `tblInp` and with a `for` loop the mutliple recorde in `tblOut` are created.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub createData()
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb    

    Dim rs As Recordset, rsOut As Recordset
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblInp")    
    Set rsOut = db.OpenRecordset("tblOut")

    Dim i As Long

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        With rsOut
            For i = rs.Fields("MinNr") To rs.Fields("MaxNr")
                .AddNew
                .Fields("Code").Value = rs.Fields("Code").Value
                .Fields("allNr").Value = i
                .Update
            Next i
            rs.MoveNext
        End With
    Loop

    rs.Close
    rsOut.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Storax! I used your code, and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time and your help!